# Why does Test-NetConnection indicate connection can be made, but I cannot visit the site?

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, firewall

I need to determine whether a particular site is accessible on a particular port, given that firewall restrictions exist on the network.

If I cannot access the site on a particular port, then that means I would need to modify the firewall before proceeding. Otherwise, if I can reach the site, then I would be able to proceed with what I intend to do.

I wanted to know whether I could fetch a repository from `Github` using the repo's https URL. An example https URL : `https://github.com/git-for-windows/git.git`. This can be used with `clone` and other tools.

To see whether I could reach `Github` and by extension, clone the repo, I ran the following command: `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName  github.com -Port 443 |findstr "TcpTestSucceeded"`

On the system, this command returned the following, indicating that I was able to reach `github.com` over port 443 (https).

`TcpTestSucceeded : True`

However, I then opened up a web browser, and visited `https://github.com`, and the web browser indicated that a connection could not be made. https is over port 443 and the domain is `github.com` just like what I put in the test.

My questions are:

- Why is there this discrepancy between the two tests?
- How can I accurately test over `CMD` or `PowerShell` whether I have access to a particular domain over a particular port?

Clearly, the `Test-NetConnection` command did not produce accurate results, as the web browser was not able to reach `github.com`.

I believe the browser, among other obvious reasons, because the network on which I ran this test is very strictly set up, and would not have expected to be able to connect.

Comment: It's a good question; I don't have an answer, but as an aside: you should use `(Test-NetConnection -ComputerName  github.com -Port 443).TcpTestSucceeded` to test for success, which directly returns a Boolean (`[bool]`) value.

Comment: "Clearly, the `Test-NetConnection` command did not produce accurate results" - that's not clear at all - your firewall might allow the initial TCP handshake but drop the connection once it detects a HTTP/HTTPS session on top. If you want to test whether you can clone a github repo: clone a github repo! :)